# 3D Model in Windows Phone 7 using Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, 3d, windows-phone-7

I have to do a wp7 app with a 3D arrow rotating dynamically. The app will have alot os menus, so the best way is use Silverlight. How can I have a 3D object in silverlight? I have tools like Swift 3D to do the model. They generate .xaml code, but when I put that code in expression blender I have errors.

There are a different approach? I'm a little lost, because I'm new to Microsoft development platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a flat 2D object and use a perspective transform, to transform it in 3D. You will get was it called a 2.5D projection.
These two posts should help you:
http://netindonesia.net/blogs/umifadilah/archive/2010/05/12/silverlight-3d-perspective-transform-on-windows-phone-7.aspx

http://pendsevikram.blogspot.com/2010/07/silverlight-on-mobile-3d-on-your.html

If you need full 3D models, I'd recommend to try the Silverlight 3D engine Balder from CodePlex: http://balder.codeplex.com
The main developer has recently written a good Coding4Fun article that might help you:
[Rubik’s Cube for Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 using Balder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2010/11/08/10087940.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to add 3d model is max2xaml plugin for 3dsmax: http://max2xaml.codeplex.com/

and you can use tool Viewer3ds:
http://www.wpf-graphics.com/Viewer3ds.aspx

Article:
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/3dsToXaml.aspx