# How do I do simple 3D in XNA on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I'm a newbie to 3D on WP7. All I want to do is nice simple 3D

A. Add/Draw a number of coloured primitives, cube and spheres etc. to a 3D world

B. Rotate the World x, y and/or z

That's it, nothing else. I don't need any collision detection, I don't need any clever physics I don't need any textures or backgrounds or anything else, just that nice and simple.

I've been through about a gazillion examples on various websites and they all obscure the basics with bloated code and objects that I just don't want. I don't want any marble or spaceship examples, just some nice clean, clear code.

I have Blender to create the 3D models and these will be simple models with no textures. just solid basic 3D objects.

Please don't point me to anything that's based on a game which every example I have already found is.

Oh and please only examples that actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Well the *best* way to do 3D on Windows Phone 7 is to use XNA which is generally associated with games which isn't the whole truth. You can still build traditional applications using XNA, although it might take you longer to construct your ui as opposed to silverlight.

You should probably check out [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com) from Microsoft as there are a ton of samples, in fact they have a category specifically for 3D. Keep in mind since your just starting you should make an attempt to understand the examples there giving you. Even though code you see for the first time might *seem* like bloated or extra code, there actually necessary components to consider when developing 3D applications.

At any rate, [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/3DGraphicsWP7.aspx) goes over the basics of 3D using XNA on Windows Phone 7.
**EDIT:** If you don't want to use XNA, there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266178/3d-model-in-windows-phone-7-using-silverlight) that was asked previously. There's a couple of solutions for using 3D in silverlight.

Comment: Yes I am using XNA. 2D XNA was ridiculously easy I had a whole game from scratch completed in under a day. 3D I can't even get started. Even getting started with Blender is a joke. Why do people that know make it so hard for people that don't. By the way the example you quote does not work.